# PATCH with Angular using false route

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, angularjs

So I am trying to make a PATCH request to my Rails server with Angular to update the role of an user.

The code that I invoke looks like this:

```
$scope.updateUser = (user, selectedRole) ->
        # Update the role of user
        $http.patch({
            url: '/users/' + user.id,
            data: {user: {id: user.id, role: selectedRole}}
        })
```

When I run this code, I can see in my Rails server log that this request was made:

```
Started POST "/[object%20Object]" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-11-29 17:59:01 +0200
```

And in the javascript console I see this:

```
PATCH http://localhost:3000/[object%20Object] 404 (Not Found)
```

Why is the route that the info is being sent an object when I clearly set it to be `'/users/userId'`?

Plnkr link: http://plnkr.co/edit/mZvD3cptkbbonz07tMqJ?p=info

Comment: Can you provide a plnkr? Just a guess, but hook with your debugger right before the patch request, and see what `'/users/' + user.id` actually returns, or what the value of `user.id` is

Comment: What exactly is a plnkr? Also, my user.id is 2.

Comment: A short snippet created at http://plnkr.co/ where you get a link that you can post here. There you can demonstrate in a short way your problem, and everyone else doesn't have to copy&paste your code to try it out.

Comment: Added the link. But it seems to not work well at all in that environment.

Comment: I found that if I write the command like this: `$http.patch('/users/' + user.id, data: {user: {id: user.id, role: selectedRole})`, then it works. But this makes the code looks less readable.

Comment: The first arg of the patch method is always the url. You also can try $http({method: "patch", url: "/foobar"}). Another syntax for the same thing